# Rendering an SVG from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, svg

I have a React project I'm working on and I'd trying to render an SVG from an array of objects. I however get an error whenever i try accessing the SVG from the map method. Is there a better way to go through the process that I'm missing. For context:

```
locations: [
            { svg: SanFrancisco, city: "San Francisco, CA", number: 54 },
            { svg: Redwood, city: "Redwood City, CA", number: 1 },
            { svg: NewYork, city: " New York, NY", number: 17 },
            { svg: Portland, city: "Portland, OR", number: 10 }
           ]
```

The SVGs have already been imported as React components here.

The usage in jsx:

```
{locations.map((location) => {
                            return (
                                <a href="#">
                                    {" "}
                                    <div className="locations-card card">
                                        {location.svg}
                                        <h2>{location.city}</h2>
                                        <p>{location.number} openings</p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            );
                        })}
```

logging *location.svg* to the console returns an object of this nature

- {$$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref), render: ƒ}$$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref)render: ƒ SvgSanfrancisco({   title,   titleId,   ...props }, svgRef)displayName: (...)get displayName: ƒ ()set displayName: ƒ (name)arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 1name: "set"prototype: {constructor: ƒ}**proto**: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: react.development.js:1401[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]**proto**: Object...*

Is it possible to access the svg icon itself via the object?

Edit: per a suggestion, the code below did the trick

```
{locations.map((location) => {
                            return (
                                <a href="#">
                                    {" "}
                                    <div className="locations-card card">
                                        <location.svg/>
                                        <h2>{location.city}</h2>
                                        <p>{location.number} openings</p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            );
                        })}
```

Comment: <img src="...">

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the svg property is a `react component`:

```
{locations.map((location) => {
    const Svg = location.svg; // --> get the component
    return (
      <a href="#">
         {" "}
       <div className="locations-card card">
           <Svg />{/* --> render it*/}
           <h2>{location.city}</h2>
           <p>{location.number} openings</p>
       </div>
      </a>
   );})}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This actually worked. Was sceptical bout trying it as such cause it was an imported component.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the component itself in the object. e.g

```
{ svg: < SanFrancisco/>, city: "San Francisco, CA", number: 54 },
```

and then render `{location.svg}`

Comment: Thanks. Already tried something similar and it worked.